# Mongodb/Mongoose: one field will not updated by empty string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

i am new in MongoDB/Mongoose and have the following problem:

my schema is nested with:

```
profile: {
school: {type: String, required: false},
subject: {type: String, required: false}, 
graduation: {type: String, required: false}
}
```

now i want to update school, subject and graduation with:

```
userRouter.put('/:id', function(req, res, next){

  var updateObject = req.body;

 User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params['id'], updateObject,{upsert: true}, (err, success)=> {
if(err)
  res.status(404).send(err);
     res.status(200).send();
  });
});
```

i know the put method replace the object, but the patch method doesn't run in my code. Now, when  i sent:

```
{"school": "", "subject": "c", "graduation": ""}
```

subject and graduation will be overwritten, but school will not be empty - it contains the old stuff.

Do you have a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tested like this school and graduation were modified...

```
    let updateObject = {
        profile: {school: "", subject: "c", graduation: ""}
    };

    user.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params['id'],
        updateObject,
        {upsert: true},
        function(err, success) {
            if (err)
                res.status(404).send(err);
            res.status(200).send();
        }
    );
```

Used this testing schema:

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    created: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
    modified: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
    profile: {
        school: {type: String, required: false},
        subject: {type: String, required: false},
        graduation: {type: String, required: false}
    }

},
{
    collection: 'db_test',
    strict: 'throw',
    toJSON: {getters: true},
    toObject: {getters: true}
}
);
```